# Coldfusion dynamic variable naming

Tags: coldfusion

It's possible with coldfusion convert this php code?

```
if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" ){

    //do something...

}
```

I have tried something as:

```
if( structKeyExists( url , "bSortable_[iSortCol_[#i#]]" ) ) {

}
```

But seems not working....probably I should try another way to make this?

The variables are two:

```
bSortable_1 = true;
iSortCol_1 = 1;
```

I should obtain bSortable_1 value....

Comment: The variables are two:

bSortable_1 = true;
iSortCol_1 = 1;

I should obtain bSortable_1 value....

Comment: My approach would be to treat the two url variables separately.

Comment: COuld you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much familiar with PHP but it seems that you are passing bSortable_1, iSortCol_1 kind of query variable to make sorting of table. I guess below code should work foe you.

```
<cfset url.bSortable_1 = 1>
<cfset url.iSortCol_1 = 1>
<!--- Option 1 --->
<cfif structKeyExists(URL,"bSortable_#URL.iSortCol_1#")>
    <cfoutput>Exists</cfoutput>
</cfif>

<!--- Option 2 --->
<cfset i = 1>
<cfif URL['bSortable_#URL['iSortCol_#i#']#']>
    <cfoutput>Exists</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Although I found this is so complex. I will suggest go for some nicer option.

Comment: URL['bSortable_#URL['iSortCol_#i#']#'] will return value

Comment: The answer is ok. Pritesh comment add more insight...I'm trying to create a server side logic for DataTables plugin...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920589/iteration-through-url-request-collection-variables-by-dynamic-evaluation my datatables , same question, different way to achiece using cfscript

Answer (score 1):

This is explanation requested in the comments.  There are at least two url variables available, bSortable_1 and iSortCol_1.  Both the php code and Pritesh's answer have this sort of structure.

```
<cfif somethingabout_bSortable_1.somethingabout_iSortCol_1>
do something
```

By treating the variables separately, my structure would resemble this:

```
<cfif somethingabout_bSortable_1 and (or or) somethingabout_iSortCol_1>
do something
```

Going to the StructkeyExists function, but with static values, it would be this

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(url, "bSortable_1") and StructKeyExists(url, "iSortCol_1")>
do something
```

For dynamic values, I don't know what would work so I would have to find out.  Having said that, the first thing I'd try is:

```
<cfloop from = "1" to = SomeMaximum index = "i">
<cfif StructKeyExists(url, "bSortable_#i#") and StructKeyExists(url, "iSortCol_#i#")>
do something
closing tags
```